# Batch file not working when using timestamp on win server 2008 r2

Tags: command-line, batch, windows-server-2008-r2

I use this command in batch file to add time stamp on file:

```
copy C:\1\1.txt C:\1\Log_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%.txt
```

It works fine on windows server 2008 R2 but it does not work on another device with the same operating system(2008 R2).

I tried another script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
copy "C:\1\1.txt" "C:\1\Log_ %stamp%.txt
```

It works fine on both servers but different outputs:

Server with problem:

```
Log_ ~0,4-~4,2-~6,2_~8,2-~10,2-~12,2.txt
```

Other server:

```
Log_ 2017-06-04_12-50-07.txt
```

Comment: [print screen of the failing server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X435p.jpg) there is no problem in WMI on the failing server @DavidPostill

Comment: Perhaps on each server you can simply go to a command prompt and type in `ECHO %date%` and them confirm the format result you get on both is the same or not. Perhaps the time formatting settings are different between the two servers and that's why you have the inconsistencies. So just simply do that and see what you determine. If they are different formats, then change the format to match the one that works and then use the same script e.g. `%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%` and be done with it.

Comment: @MohamedTag Clearly there is as indicated by the `ERROR: Code = 0x80020009 Description = Exception occurred. Facility = Dispatch` error message.

Answer (score 0):

#### It works fine on both servers but different outputs

Try the following batch file (which is the correct way to parse the local time output from `wmic`):

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%g in (`wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set _day=00%%g
  set _hours=00%%h
  set _minutes=00%%i
  set _month=00%%j
  set _seconds=00%%k
  set _year=%%l
  )
rem pad with leading zeros
set _month=%_month:~-2%
set _day=%_day:~-2%
set _hh=%_hours:~-2%
set _mm=%_minutes:~-2%
set _ss=%_seconds:~-2%
set _stamp=%_year%%_month%%_day%%_hh%%_mm%%_ss%
copy "C:\1\1.txt" "C:\1\Log_ %_stamp%.txt"
endlocal
```

---

#### This code is still failing on a particular server, with error code 0x80020009

> `Z:\>wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year ERROR: Code = 0x80020009 Description = Exception occurred. Facility = Dispatch`

The error code 80041002 indicates a missing or corrupt wmi repository on the failing machine.

> The key to solving the problem here is the error code 80041002, which [in WMI terms means Object cannot be found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, this is the COM/OLE subsystem for WMI (aka WBEM) complaining that it cannot find the requested WMI class or value.

The solution is to fix the WMI repository:

> **How to fix a missing or corrupted WMI repository**
>
> In order to fix a corrupted WMI repository, first run a disk check
>   (`chkdsk`) to make sure that the corruption is not at the storage level.
>   D’uh. Next, check that the WMI Control snap-in does indeed have
>   difficulty in connecting to WMI; it should complain about ‘Failed to
>   initialize all required WMI classes’:
>
> [image]
>
> Then pick one of the three kinds of fixes for broken WMI repositories:
>   the simple, the sordid, or the scary:
>
> - Simple: run `winmgmt /salvagerepository` against the local WMI repository
> - Sordid: restore the WMI repository from a WMI backup (if you have one)
> - Scary: re-install Windows from the rescue disk

Source [Chef on Windows – detecting and fixing WMI problems which prevent chef-client runs](https://engineering.thetrainline.com/2013/07/09/chef-on-windows-detecting-and-fixing-wmi-problems/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [getdate](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-getdate.html) - Display the date and time independent of OS Locale, Language or the users chosen date format (Control Panel/Regional).
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: i tried your script and gave me this output(Log_ ~-2~-2~-2~-2~-2.txt) and the same script works fine on other device and this is the problem

Comment: @MohamedTag I've noticed there was a missing `"` after `C:\1\Log_ %_stamp%.txt` (answer corrected). Does that fix it?

Comment: What is the output of `wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year` on the failing machine?

Comment: (") has no effect on script because the script run well on other device with same OS but different output (~-2~-2~-2~-2~-2.txt) on failing device and (Log_ 20170604142449.txt) on all other devices

Comment: @MohamedTag Then your script is broken. There is a space in the target filename and mismatched quotes.

Comment: @MohamedTag What is the output of `wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year` on the failing machine?

Comment: thanks for support but i copy the file from the working device to the non working device and i did not edit it

Comment: @MohamedTag *sigh* What is the output of `wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year` on the failing machine? I'm trying to help you dbug why it is not working.

Comment: Z:\>wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year
ERROR:
Code = 0x80020009
Description = Exception occurred.
Facility = Dispatch

    Z:\> @DavidPostill

Comment: @MohamedTag You have a missing or corrupt wmi repository on the failing machine. Answer updated to address your error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't related to the batch Mohamed is using.

[DavidPostill's](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) assertion `(which is the correct way to parse the local time output from wmic)` is at least doubtful. There is no **one** correct way. IMO it's of no use to get the single date/time elements and stuff the leading zeroes afterwards.

You will get the same failing output if the var `dt` is **not** defined.
So either

- there was an error transferring the batch to the other server or
- as also the single line fails with the internal variables `%date%` and `%time%` it might be a wrong `cmd.exe` in the path be involved.

---

There is no need to put the date/time elements into vars before assembling the `stamp`

```
@Echo off
For /f "delims=." %%D in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') Do "Set dt=%%D"
Set stamp=%dt:~0,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%_%dt:~8,2%-%dt:~10,2%-%dt:~12,2%
Echo copy "C:\1\1.txt" "C:\1\Log_%stamp%.txt
```

The Echo in the last line avoids errors while testing, remove it when the output seems ok.

Comment: That doesn't explain the `ERROR: Code = 0x80020009 Description = Exception occurred. Facility = Dispatch` on the failing server.